# ActiveCampaign: Get Page URL where the form had been submitted

Tags: javascript, activecampaign

I have a Wordpress website and my forms are managed by ActiveCampaign. The main contact form is in the footer of every page and I would like to know from which page the user submits the form.
I would be able to do it if I could set an ID to the single field but it seems there is no way to do it in ActiveCampaign.
I only have a variable called %LANDING% (a hidden field I created) that maybe can valorized someway, any idea on how to manage it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page URL using javascript to a hidden field in the form as explained in the following article:
https://help.activecampaign.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012822040-What-page-was-a-contact-on-when-they-submitted-a-form-#technical-use-hidden-fields-and-java-script-1

Hope this is what you were looking for.